# What is the Cleanup merit badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I see a Cleanup merit badge, which is described as "First rollback", but it has no information on how to earn it and no explanation as to what a rollback means?  Is this deleting your earlier question or deleting a comment or answer?  If so, we should state that in the right section.

Comment: I don't know why I am laughing tears here, J.  I had no idea there was a cleanup merit badge (this is sounding like 'Brownies or Bluebirds or babyscouts).  I have no idea what cleanup would mean!

Answer (score 7):

A rollback is when you edit a post to revert it to an earlier version. If a post has previously been edited (such that it has at least two revisions), when you look at its edit history you'll see a `rollback` link underneath the older revisions.

For example, my [recent question about artificial plants](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/are-questions-about-installing-artificial-plants-on-topic) has [two revisions](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/804/revisions):

[image]

Revision 1 shows the `rollback` link. Clicking on that<sup>1</sup> would create a revision 3, which would be identical to revision 1.

For more information see the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) and some posts on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)
- [How can I get the "cleanup" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/how-can-i-get-the-cleanup-badge)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Don't! Use [this](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/stack-exchange-experimentation-sandbox) if you absolutely must experiment.</sup>

Comment: Having a footnote to a meta answer should be a badge in itself.  Nicely done